# Shorter way to select the leftmost and rightmost points from a sequence?

Tags: c++

I have tried to find points (named A, B, and C, D) from a set of points (a point has x- and y- coordinates).
A and B are the points that are leftmost points and C and D are the points that are rightmost points among the points set.

Additionally, A and B are the points that have the same x- coords but B has bigger y- coords than A.
C and D are the points that have the same x- coords but D has bigger y- coords than C.

Here is the for loop for that.

```
// pointSeq is a vector of points
// A,B,C and D are set to pointSeq[0]
for(int i = 1 ; i < pointSeq.size(); i++)
{
    if (pointSeq[i].x <= A.x)
    {
        if(pointSeq[i].x < A.x)
        {
            A = pointSeq[i]; B = pointSeq[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if(pointSeq[i].y > B.y)
            {
                B = pointSeq[i];
            }
            else if(pointSeq[i].y < A.y)
            {
                A = pointSeq[i];
            }
        }
    }
    // from here it is to find the C and D
    else if (pointSeq[i].x >= C.x)
    {
        if(pointSeq[i].x > C.x)
        {
            C = pointSeq[i], D = pointSeq[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if (pointSeq[i].y > D.y)
            {
                D = pointSeq[i];    
            }
            else if (pointSeq[i].y < C.y)
            {
                C = pointSeq[i];
            }
        }   
    }

}
```

These two parts are very similar procedure so I wonder if I can shorten the code to make it simpler.

I would like to make the question simple. It finds the four points that are located in each x-min and x-max position. 
I can add more lines to find points with respect to y- coordinates (i.e., four points for y-min and y max, in this case x- coordinates are different).

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)?

Comment: As a note, this code is pretty thin on explanation and is far from being self-explanatory. I'd try and boil it down into a more specific objective: Why are you setting those variables, and under what conditions do they get set? Can you just sort this list of points and get it over with in one pass?

Comment: this code already is too short, ie it is missing any declarations...

Comment: To answer the question you asked: yes, you can certainly shorten the code to make it simpler.

Comment: Just find `A` and `D` in one loop, then define `B` and `C` from them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Okay, then how?

Comment: Sort the points. Simple sort by X and Y coordinates. Take the first two points, and the last two points, in the sorted list. One call to `std::sort()`. The four assignments, to A, B, C, and D. Five statements total, instead of all of this tangled logic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because CodeReview.stackexchange.com is the appropriate place to ask for improving coding of working code.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, thank you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sure, but I want to find it without sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way of simplifying what you're doing here is to think about defining a way of comparing points against one another. Given two points (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) and (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>), consider the lexicographical comparison of those points, which could be done via this function:

```
bool lexCompare(Point lhs, Point rhs) {
    return (lhs.x < rhs.x) || (lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y < rhs.y);
}
```

This comparison first looks at the x coordinates of the two points. If they're different, it ranks the points against one another purely using the x coordinate. Otherwise, if the x coordinates are the same, then the comparison looks at the y coordinates to break ties.

You're looking at getting the two leftmost points and the two rightmost points, specifically, grabbing the two leftmost points with the lowest y coordinates and the two rightmost points with the highest y coordinates. If you think about it, what you're doing here is essentially asking for A and B to be the two lexicographically smallest points in the set and for C and D to be the two lexicographically greatest points in the set. That way, A has the lowest x coordinate of all the points and, of the possible choices for x with the lowest x coordinate, has the lowest possible y coordinate. D then has the highest possible x coordinate and, of the options available, picks the one with the highest possible y coordinate.

The good news is that the standard libraries have a ton of functions available for finding these sorts of values. For example, if you want something dead simple that's decently efficient, you could just sort the points according to this metric:

```
std::sort(pointSeq.begin(), pointSeq.end(),
          [](const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
              return (lhs.x < rhs.x) || (lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y < rhs.y);
          });
Point A = pointSeq[0];
Point B = pointSeq[1];
Point C = pointSeq[pointSeq.size() - 2];
Point D = pointSeq[pointSeq.size() - 1];
```

This runs in time O(n log n), which is slower than what you have above, but is much more compact.

Another option would be to use to use `std::minmax_element` to find the min and max points (A and D, respectively), then to pull those elements out and do a second `std::minmax_element` to find B and C:

```
auto comparator = [](const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
                       return (lhs.x < rhs.x) || (lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y < rhs.y);
                  };
auto aAndD = std::minmax_element(pointSeq.begin(), pointSeq.end(), comparator);
Point A = *aAndD.first;
Point D = *aAndD.second;

/* Move A and D to the end of the sequence. */
if (aAndD.first > aAndD.second) std::swap(aAndD.first, std::aAndD.second);
std::iter_swap(aAndD.second, pointSeq.end() - 1);
std::iter_swap(aAndD.first,  pointSeq.end() - 2);

/* Get B and C. */
auto bAndC = std::minmax_element(pointSeq.begin(), pointSeq.end() - 2);
Point B = *bAndC.first;
Point C = *bAndC.second;
```

This code runs in time O(n) and more compactly conveys what you're trying to do.

Or use `std::nth_element` to reorder the elements to put the top two and bottom two elements into the right place:

```
auto comparator = [](const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
                       return (lhs.x < rhs.x) || (lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y < rhs.y);
                  };
std::nth_element(pointSeq.begin(), pointSeq.begin() + 1, pointSeq.end(), comparator);
std::nth_element(pointSeq.begin() + 2, pointSeq.end() - 2, pointSeq.end(), comparator);

/* Sort the two-element ranges at the beginning and end. */
if (comparator(pointSeq[0], pointSet[1])) {
    std::swap(pointSeq[0], pointSeq[1]);
}
if (comparator(pointSeq[pointSeq.size() - 2], pointSeq[pointSeq.size() - 1]) {
    std::swap(pointSeq[pointSeq.size() - 2], pointSeq[pointSeq.size() - 1]);
}

Point A = pointSeq[0];
Point B = pointSeq[1];
Point C = pointSeq[pointSeq.size() - 2];
Point D = pointSeq[pointSeq.size() - 1];
```